# WebPack SCSS error "uknown word" on variable used as keyframe step percentage

Tags: webpack, sass

The error Webpack (version 4.0.0) throws:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./~/postcss-loader!./src/index.scss
Module build failed: Unknown word (740:5)

  738 |   }
  739 | 
> 740 |   #{$pulse-percent} {
      |     ^
  741 |     background-position: $mask-right-end 0;
  742 |   }
```

The relevant SCSS:

```
// simplified for this question...
$pulse-percent: .6 / 5 * 100%;

@keyframes pulseBG {
  // other steps...

  // ERROR on this line
  #{$pulse-percent} {
    background-position: $mask-right-end 0;
  }

  // other steps...    
}
```

The syntax I'm using is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31084393/870729).

I've tried a several syntax variations with no luck:

```
// throws "expect ':' after $pulse-percent in assignment statement
$pulse-percent { 

// throws "unknown word"
{$pulse-percent} {

// throws "unknown word"
#{( $variable1 / $variable2 * 100% )} {
```

Other resources on Google that I have found don't seem to address this scenario, and / or seem outdated.

Other variables are being processed properly.

Any "interpolation" syntax I try to use fails.  Another line in my SCSS that fails is `animation: #{$pulse-interval} pulseBG 1s linear infinite;`

*Yes, it's a silly CSS animation in a serious web application.*
*Yes, I could just enter the values to work around the problem.*
But, I'd like to understand the problem and how to resolve it.

Comment: What version of Webpack are you using?

Comment: Webpack version is 4 (`^4.0.0` in package.json), and `yarn list` indicates `webpack@4.1.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug on version 4.0.0 of Webpack, This issue is resolved since version 4.1.1 of Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Between Nov 2017 (version 4.0.0) and version 4.1.1, Webpack appears to have resolved this issue.  I could not find in the changelog any mention of this issue, however testing reveals that it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add `lang="scss"` to the `<style>` tag. This occurred in a vue project which is not using webpack.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  ...
</style>
```