# Sass unknow word issue

Tags: sass, webpack-4

With the following sass code:

```
section {
    @each $name, $variable in $themes {
        &.theme-#{$name} {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

When the code compiles I'm getting the following error:

```
(26:19) C:\<AppPath>\www\sass\components\custom\slide_out_panel.scss Unknown word

  24 | section.is-slide-out-panel {
  25 |     @each $name, $variable in $themes {
> 26 |         &.theme-#{$name} {
     |                   ^
```

I saw the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112841/webpack-scss-error-uknown-word-on-variable-used-as-keyframe-step-percentage) that says it was an issue with webpack 4.0.0.  But I'm using the following versions:

```
"webpack": "^5.62.1",
"webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file module for the sass and CSS:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            options: {
                configFile: 'tsconfig-www.json',
            },
        },
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
        },
    ],
},
```

**Update**
It seems like removing 'postcss-loader' fixed the issue.

Comment: If you were able to fix the issue, rather than updating the original question, you should [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), which will give a better indication to visitors to the page how to fix the problem and should provide you opportunities to get reputation points for your answer.

Comment: I can do that, I was hoping that others may have another solution in case its a setting I have incorrect.